# SQL Performance timeouts , vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, performance

I have a vb.net web application and when a particular function runs , i get data timeouts in the rest of the application..(ie..row not found errors or column does not belong to table but it does)

The function is adding multiple rows in multiple tables in the database and is running in a for loop. It seems to be all SQL related but I am not seeing anything in the error logs in SQL or in the application

Right now I am assuming it is memory related but I am looking for some suggestions on where to start

note..the for loop will be replaced with a bulk insert but right now I jest need to resolve the issue of the timeouts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a data storage process is adding rows into your database in several incremental steps, within your for loop. If you refactor that process into one bulk insert like you're thinking, it will resolve the issue of row not found errors. What may be happening is that in your system, users are concurrently accessing records that are getting incrementally added. The programming source code likely expects the entire unit of data to exist, and as the data insert loop is not complete, it causes a runtime exception.

Any concurrent system should insert data in an atomic fashion. If not, errors like this will typically occur.